# PHP - cookie encryption and hmac signing

Tags: php, cookies, encryption, signature

I was just wondering is it redundant to encrypt and sign a cookie? Isn't encryption enough? Why or why not?

If it's not redundant, I'm wondering if I'm going about this in the right direction. For simplicity's sake, what I've done is this:

```
$data = 'some data';
$encrypted_data = mcrypt_encrypt($cipher, $key, $data, $mode, $iv);
$signature = hash_hmac($algorithm, $data, $key);
$package = $encrypted_data . '|' . $signature;
setcookie('somecookie', $package, time()+60*60*24);
```

From what I basically understand is, you're hmac hashing the data and with a delimiter you're appending it onto your encrypted data? Then later you do all your validation and so on when you're checking the cookie. Am I approaching this correctly? Also, should all the keys for encryption and signing be nonces (single time used key) or is it enough for each of them to be a single global key shared by all? I apologize that this is becoming a 3-parter question. Hope that no one minds. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

> I was just wondering is it redundant to encrypt and sign a cookie? Isn't encryption enough? Why or why not?

Unless you're using a newer AEAD interface, [encryption doesn't protect against chosen-ciphertext attacks](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/05/using-encryption-and-authentication-correctly).

> From what I basically understand is, you're hmac hashing the data and with a delimiter you're appending it onto your encrypted data? Then later you do all your validation and so on when you're checking the cookie. Am I approaching this correctly?

What you've written here is an **Encrypt and MAC** construction. You want **Encrypt then MAC** instead.

```
- $signature = hash_hmac($algorithm, $data, $key);
+ $signature = hash_hmac($algorithm, $encrypted_data, $key);
```

Even better, don't write it yourself if you don't have to. Feel free to use `sodium_crypto_secretbox()` and `sodium_crypto_secretbox_open()` instead. [See the examples here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30159120/2224584).