# How to encrypt and decrypt data in php?

Tags: php, encryption

How to encrypt and decrypt data in php?

My code so far is:-

```
function encrypter($plaintext)
{
    $plaintext = strtolower($plaintext);
    $crypttext = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256,FLENCKEY,$plaintext,MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);    
    return trim(base64_encode($crypttext));
}

function decrypter($crypttext)
{
    $crypttext = base64_decode($crypttext);    
    $plaintext = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256,FLENCKEY,$crypttext,MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);    
    return trim($crypttext);
}
```

$test = "abc@gmail.com";

echo encrypter(test);

**Output is**

```
iLmUJHKPjPmA9vY0jfQ51qGpLPWC/5bTYWFDOj7Hr08=
```

echo decrypter(test);

**Output is**

```
��-
```

Comment: wouldn't you be wanting to decrypt the encrypted data, as opposed to trying to decrpt `$test` which is already decrypted?

Comment: Do not encrypt anything if you are not good at it. I know barely enough about encryption to know that if you fail at it, no hacker will point it out to you. While it might be a good idea to use Rijndael 256, which is basically AES 256 you obviously do not know the importance of encryption mode as ECB is very bad. (However this is mitigated by the short length of your data)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you Encrypt and Decrypt a PHP String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16600708/how-do-you-encrypt-and-decrypt-a-php-string)

Answer (score 2):

In your `decrypter()` function, you return the wrong data.

You should return `$plaintext` instead of `$crypttext`:

```
function decrypter($crypttext)
{
    $crypttext = base64_decode($crypttext);    
    $plaintext = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256,FLENCKEY,$crypttext,MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);    
    //return trim($crypttext);
    return trim($plaintext);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The other code samples on this page (including the question) are not secure.

To be secure:

1. [Don't use mcrypt](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/05/if-you-re-typing-word-mcrypt-into-your-code-you-re-doing-it-wrong).
2. [Use authenticated encryption](https://tonyarcieri.com/all-the-crypto-code-youve-ever-written-is-probably-broken).
3. [Never use ECB mode (a.k.a. `MCRYPT_MODE_ECB`)](https://blog.filippo.io/the-ecb-penguin).

#### See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30159120/2224584) for secure encryption in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use. Super simple.

```
function encrypt_decrypt($action, $string) {
   $output = false;
   $key = '$b@bl2I@?%%4K*mC6r273~8l3|6@>D';
   $iv = md5(md5($key));
   if( $action == 'encrypt' ) {
       $output = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($key), $string, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
       $output = base64_encode($output);
   }
   else if( $action == 'decrypt' ){
       $output = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($key), base64_decode($string), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
       $output = rtrim($output, "");
   }
   return $output;
}
```

You can change `$key` to whatever you want, or leave it. (this is not my key, btw)

`encrypt_decrypt('encrypt', $str)` to encrypt

`encrypt_decrypt('decrypt', $str)` to decrypt

Answer (score 0):

Inside the decrypter function, change the

```
return trim($crypttext);
```

to

```
return trim($plaintext);
```

But looking at your function, I am not quite sure whether it will return exactly the same string, because of the strtolower function. You can't just do a strtoupper function as the original text may not be all in capital letters.

Answer (score 0):

**Warning**
**mcrypt_encrypt** has been **DEPRECATED** as of PHP 7.1.0. Relying on this function is highly discouraged.
Use **openssl_encrypt** instead.