# mcrypt_decrypt not working when used in other php file

Tags: php, mysql, encryption, lampp

I am creating login where registered user can Login with there Emailid and password(use Lampp).

I have one form where user are registering with there information that is User Name, EmailID, password etc.

then while inserting data in mysql database i am encrypting password.

the code is:

```
<?php


    define("ENCRYPTION_KEY", "!@#$%^&*");

    $finalarray=array();


    $finalarray['UserName']= $_POST["fname"];

    $finalarray['EmailID']= $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['pwd'];

   $encrypted = encryptIt( $input );
    $finalarray['Password']= $encrypted;



function encryptIt( $q ) 
{
    $cryptKey  = 'qJB0rGtIn5UB1xG03efyCp';
    $qEncoded      = base64_encode( mcrypt_encrypt( MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5( $cryptKey ), $q, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5( md5( $cryptKey ) ) ) );
    return( $qEncoded );
}  


/* code for insert into database */


?>
```

when user is login it is cross check the email id and password in the database.

so for that i wrote decrypt function to match the password and if emailid match with password then user will login.

the code is:

```
<?php
include 'ConnectionDatabase.php'; /database connnection
define("ENCRYPTION_KEY", "!@#$%^&*");


ob_start();
session_start();

$username = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];




$connection= connection();  //connected

$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
$query = "SELECT  EmailID,Password
        FROM User
        WHERE EmailID = ".'$username';






$result = mysql_query($query);

if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) // User not found. So, redirect to login_form again.
{
   echo "Not Valid User";
   header('Location: login.html');
}



$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);

$encryptpassword=$row[1];

echo $encryptpassword."<br>";


$decrypted = decryptIt($encryptpassword);




echo $decrypted; //no value is coming




if($password != $decrypted ) // Incorrect password. So, redirect to login_form again.
{
    header('Location: login_fb.php');
}else{ // Redirect to home page after successful login.
       echo "login";
    session_regenerate_id();
    $_SESSION['sess_user_id'] = $userData['id'];
    $_SESSION['sess_username'] = $userData['username'];
    session_write_close();
    //header('Location: creatememorial.php');
}



function decryptIt( $q ) {
    $cryptKey  = 'qJB0rGtIn5UB1xG03efyCp';
    $qDecoded      = rtrim( mcrypt_decrypt( MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5( $cryptKey ), base64_decode( $q ), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5( md5( $cryptKey ) ) ), "\0");
    return( $qDecoded );
}
?>
```

**echo $decrypted;** not printing any think.

i referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16600708/php-string-encrypt-and-decrypt) link when i did this in one program its working.

when i am using this two php file its not working.

i dont know what is the problem.

can any one help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

You're going a very long way round this.

Just encrypt the users password and use the encrypted password in the database query.

Example:

```
$username = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$connection = connection();

$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
$password = encryptIt(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']));

$query = "SELECT  EmailID,Password
          FROM User
          WHERE EmailID = '".$username."' AND Password = '".$password."';
```

If it returns a row - there is a user with that email, and that password.

As a side note; it's no longer recommended to use `mysql_*` functions - you should switch to the `mysqli_*` library, or even better, use prepared statements.

Also - you use MD5 which generates a hash, you cannot decrypt a hash - it's a one way conversion.

Comment: Thank for reply. but when i am inserting password in database                          in encrypting fcygGLqlfhk6J7w7XuMGWgpQOJWizlAUFi2Yt5/Q68xM=  and in  login the same password is zPr2eL6eOtJXa91J9W+C/XG32j4bvk0lZ5AmcFS9vR4=  i am not getting what is the problem please help me on this.

Comment: Yes, so if you encrypt the password entered by the user at login - it will match the string in the database if it is correct.

Comment: the password is same. but it is giving different value. what is the problem