# Encryption using javascript and decryption using php

Tags: javascript, php, encryption

I have encrypted the data on clientside using javascript by using the following methods.

```
var en_uname = CryptoJS.DES.encrypt(uname, "networks");
var en_pwd = CryptoJS.DES.encrypt(pwd, "networks");
```

Now I would like to decrypt them at server sude using php. How do I do that?

Comment: whats wrong with php function? and use ssl certificate?

Comment: Please don't use DES. It's not secure anymore. CryptoJS provides TDEA/3DES and AES. Also, you can use the [password-based approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27582253/1816580) in PHP and JavaScript, but you really should be using PBKDF2 to derive a key from the password.

Answer (score 0):

You can not easily decrypt some encrypted value without having the encryption algorithm ! I guess you just want to compare the encrypted string with something... In that case you can encrypt the second value on your server-side app and just compare the two encrypted strings.

```
var a = encrypt('foo');
var b = encrypt('bar');
if 'foo' == 'bar' then 'a' is also == 'b'
```

Comment: well what you are telling is true about hash but not for every kind of encryption http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948322/fundamental-difference-between-hashing-and-encryption-algorithms

Answer (score 0):

Since java script code can be viewed in client side, If you use symmetric key encryption the key is exposed. So better use asymmetric key encryption.

Try [jcryption](http://www.jcryption.org/)

It uses OpenSSL.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.jcryption.3.0.1.js"></script>
```

And than call jCryption on your form

```
$(function() {
    $("form").jCryption();
});
```

[image]

Comment: jCruption looks nice,+1 but still i havent found need to use this

Comment: How exactly does this answer the question?

Comment: Don't use JCryption. It uses PKCS1v1.5 padding for RSA decryption, which was proven vulnerable by Daniel Bleichenbacher in 1998.

Comment: jcryption url is dead.