# How to AES decrypt data encrypted in Javascript with Python?

Tags: javascript, python, aes, pycrypto, cryptojs

I have a javascript code from a page that looks like

```
var link = '{"ct":"AAQz1rUDqp849MRxu0tqGRGvPcLzVG24xa5zbYxpwVHH6Z2p95xPPzNhMIRMcaTPvijE71RQU1X3cQhtnXdRScA6UBiLWNs9vMul2gldnMTpT92sDYHl+hKBGy2dR22Un7ElToipSqeqRrwhEK8T9ROMChrBw8i7JOICpOYoVhqDB72BH2RG\/PqjRqsKittES5BVhTTY9cs+zQI0rM+FQA62bVCL57P3RD+E+aWJJLjUvoXBqct6Jc5W7li9mk9udgn9rPKkCbXSCvwIxcWS5C1kw4uSO7y0IlovaTWLAIw5nY0l4REjbC1wPWrtxDWLlr8J+\/sQdDF+P61VHz6yiC+w56QLDjVwz4kBl3r3uP\/VZ7kUuLwWHSHnbmmXv31f","iv":"feae762ac889376169708872d9676319","s":"9b2328e8a4ee2717"}';
var msg = "f12c8b59265dc1e898135211cc30be49";    
var finalUrl = JSON.parse(CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(link, msg, {format: CryptoJSAesJson}).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
```

I figure that ct is encrypted msg, s is for Salt and iv is iv

I am trying to decode the finalUrl with python.

```
AES = AESDecrypter()
decryptor = AES.new(s, AES.MODE_CBC, IV=iv)
dec = decryptor.decrypt(ct)
```

I know it is not going to work as I can't figure how to use

```
var msg = "f12c8b59265dc1e898135211cc30be49"
```

in Python.
Also figured that `CryptoJSAesJson` may have some extra function.
Someone please show me steps how I can retrieve the finalUrl with Python with the data given here.
Any suggestion is really appreciated. Apology for my poor coding knowledge.

Comment: link to the definition of [`CryptoJSAesJson`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/meetio/cryptojs-aes/master/aes-json-format.js)

Answer (score 3):

The actual AES key is derived by the following procedure (derived from https://stackoverflow.com/a/27582253/5722339):

0. Required libraries.

   ```
   import base64;
   import hashlib;
   from Crypto.Cipher import AES;
   ```
1. Decode the provided inputs to raw bytes from hex or base64 string.

   ```
   ct = base64.b64decode("AAQz1rUDqp849MRx ... bmmXv31f");
   iv = bytes.fromhex("feae762ac889376169708872d9676319");
   salt = bytes.fromhex("9b2328e8a4ee2717");

   # In your case, the pass phrase is NOT a hex-encoded byte array.
   #  It is directly used as bytes.
   pass_phrase = b"f12c8b59265dc1e898135211cc30be49";
   ```
2. Hash the pass phrase and the salt with MD5 digest to derive the first 128 bits (16 bytes) of the key.

   ```
   md = hashlib.md5();
   md.update(pass_phrase);
   md.update(salt);
   cache0 = md.digest();
   ```
3. Hash the previously derived 16 bytes, followed by the pass phrase and the salt with MD5 digest again to derive the latter 128 bits (16 bytes) of the key.

   ```
   md = hashlib.md5();
   md.update(cache0);
   md.update(pass_phrase);
   md.update(salt);
   cache1 = md.digest();
   ```
4. Concatenate the two byte arrays to acquire the 256 bits AES key.

   ```
   key = cache0 + cache1;
   ```
5. Finally, decrypt the cipher text using 256 bits AES with CBC mode.

   ```
   cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv);
   result = cipher.decrypt(ct);
   ```

   The decrypted data is now stored in the `result` as a byte array.

Please node that while the cipher text `ct` in your sample input is base64 encoded, and the `salt` and `iv` are both hex encoded, the pass phrase is NOT hex encoded (although it looks like that).

Also you might need to un-pad the output first before using it. The un-pad function can be achieved by using lambda: (solution from https://stackoverflow.com/a/12525165/5722339)

```
unpad = lambda s : s[:-ord(s[len(s)-1:])];
```

The output of your sample input is:
`http:\/\/pmd.dittotv3.com.edgesuite.net\/draco\/shows\/Zee_Bangla\/Dweep_Jwele_Jai\/July\/19072016\/Webisode\/Dweep_Jwele_Jai_Webisode_19072016_100.mp4?key1=ozee.com&hdnea=st=1469018324~exp=1469020124~acl=%2F%2A~hmac=07e8cf2b49f51899f60b129f3a99eb792f45e779fbdae94d4a70215398fc590d`