# Decrypt with Rijndael 128 ecb using javascript in a simple html page

Tags: javascript, encryption, rijndael, ecb

I want to decrypt an encrypted cipher like 4vEUkMYlT2qJq+9J0GT8VQ== using Rijndael 128 ecb algorithm. I found some library but nothing work correctly. some of libraries only work with nodejs others work with php. I have only a simple html page that get an encrypt text from an ajax.and I want to decrypt using same algorithm Rijndael 128 ecb. (encrypt text is 4vEUkMYlT2qJq+9J0GT8VQ== decrypted result is Novaphen)
can every one give me a solution to decrypt with javascript?

Comment: You haven't asked a question.  You should edit to include a question.  Make sure the question you ask is actually on topic as per the [help].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally I can do it with this link. : [Encrypt with PHP, Decrypt with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24337317/encrypt-with-php-decrypt-with-javascript-cryptojs)
Here is my Decryption function :

```
    function DecryptData(encryptedData) {
    var decryptedText = null;
    try {
        // Mcrypt pads a short key with zero bytes
        key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('doctorlinktechno')

        iv = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('keee')

        // Keep the ciphertext in Base64 form
        ciphertext = '4vEUkMYlT2qJq+9J0GT8VQ=='

        // Mcrypt uses ZERO padding
        plaintext = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(ciphertext, key, { iv: iv, mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB, padding: CryptoJS.pad.ZeroPadding })

        // I ran this in nodejs
        return CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.stringify(plaintext);
    }
    //Malformed UTF Data due to incorrect password
    catch (err) {
        return "";
    }
}
```

the point is you must to include dependent files base on your work. for example I want to use ecb mode and padding zero and I included following files:

```
<script src="scripts/aes/core.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/aes/enc-base64.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/aes/cipher-core.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/aes/aes.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/aes/mode-ecb.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/aes/pad-zeropadding.js"></script>
```