# Which algorithm is best for encryption in php and storing in database and then decryption in nodejs

Tags: php, node.js, encryption

I want to encrypt data using PHP and store it in SQL database having a field in varchar and then decrypt in Node js and process it. What should be the encryption, I tried with **openssl_encrypt** but not able to decrypt in Node js tried with **aes-js** module.

Comment: what do you want to encrypt?

Comment: A list of FCM server keys using PHP and Decrypt it using Nodejs as our backend is created in Nodejs.

Comment: This is too broad.  There is no "best algorithm".  Ask about a specific issue and post your code.

Comment: Ok, then I want to know the easy way to encrypt the FCM server keys using PHP and decrypt the same keys by using Node Js.
How to achieve that?

Comment: AES is probably the easiest because it's most widely supported.  I say again, post your code, show what you've tried.

Comment: PHP code generates encrypted data  http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/nurm-t0jf      I am tring to decrypt with https://www.npmjs.com/package/aes-js but not able to acheive yet.

Comment: Yeah... You should edit your question to include the code you've tried in both languages. We don't write code for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, Luke for trying to help me
I got the answer in another post in StackOverflow, I am sharing the link so, that if anyone facing this problem like me can reuse the code.
[Encrypt with PHP, Decrypt with Javascript (cryptojs)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24337317/encrypt-with-php-decrypt-with-javascript-cryptojs)