# JSON decrypt in JavaScript encrypt in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, aes, cryptojs

I am encrypting with PHP a JSON file like this:

```
0: {ID: 0, NAME: "London", REGION: "ENGLAND", …}
1: {ID: 1, NAME: "Rome", REGION: "ITALY", …}
```

And I am using this library [crypt in PHP decrypt in JS AES](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27582253/)

```
function cryptoJsAesEncrypt($passphrase, $value){
$salt = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(8);
$salted = '';
$dx = '';
while (strlen($salted) < 48) {
    $dx = md5($dx.$passphrase.$salt, true);
    $salted .= $dx;
}
$key = substr($salted, 0, 32);
$iv  = substr($salted, 32,16);
$encrypted_data = openssl_encrypt(json_encode($value), 'aes-256-cbc', $key, true, $iv);
$data = array("ct" => base64_encode($encrypted_data), "iv" => bin2hex($iv), "s" => bin2hex($salt));
return json_encode($data);
}
```

I can easily encrypt in PHP and write to server (writing a JSON file) with a 128bit key like

```
$key = "TjWnZq4t7w!z%C*F";
$ForecastArray_crypt= cryptoJsAesEncrypt($key, $ForecastArray);
file_put_contents('ukforecastlist_example_crypt.json', $ForecastArray_crypt);
```

The problem is that when I try to decrypt in JavaScript with the call

```
var ukforecastlist_decrypt = JSON.parse(CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(myjson.ct, "TjWnZq4t7w!z%C*F", {format: CryptoJSAesJson}).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
```

The console returns:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token V in JSON at position 0
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at Object.parse (core_uk.js:33)
at Object._parse (aes.js:30)
at Object.decrypt (aes.js:31)
at Object.decrypt (aes.js:25)
at <anonymous>:1:54
```

Where `V` is indeed the first letter of `myjson.ct`.

What am I doing wrong? I did get the JSON with jQuery and parsed and stored it in myjson variable.

Comment: What happens if you call the decrypt function without JSON.parse? Does that work, or result in an error?

Comment: That's not valid JSON.

Comment: without JSON.parse I seem to get the same error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token K in JSON at position 4
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.parse (core_uk.js:33)
    at Object._parse (aes.js:30)
    at Object.decrypt (aes.js:31)
    at Object.decrypt (aes.js:25)
    at <anonymous>:1:44 `                  but because tonight the "ct" changed to 8480KJN...  it is flagging red the first K in position 4...weird

Comment: the short call `CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(ukforecastlist_crypt.ct, "TjWnZq4t7w!z%C*F")` runs without errors but the JSON comes out with a series of nonsense numbers

Comment: MD5 has been compromised and is no longer a useful cryptographic hash. Make every effort to avoid using it.

Comment: I am not particularly affectionate to MD5, that 's the only library I could find which I could also understand. If you know a better method (for a beginner like I am) to encrypt a JSON in PHP and decrypt it in JS ...please I 'd be really grateful. So far, that was the only one I could properly implement

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
I am now using this simple PHP class:

https://github.com/henrya/projects/blob/master/JsEncode/jsencode.class.php

I can encode in PHP with:

```
$json_data = json_encode($myArray);

$d = new jsEncode();

$myArray_enc = $d->encodeString($json_data,$key);
```

And decode in JS with:

```
var myArray_decoded = JSON.parse(jsEncode.encode(myArray_enc,key));
```