# Decrypt laravel's encryption value in node js with crypto-js

Tags: node.js, laravel, cryptojs

I'm using `encrypt()` method in my `laravel 7.0` project and I want to decrypt the encrypted value in my node project using `crypto-js`. Anyone know how to do that? Thanks!

Comment: That's apples and oranges... you can't decrypt something what  is encrypted with something else.... you will have to decrypt with laravel because it's encrypted with laravel, or encrypt with crypto-js so you can decrypt with crypto-js

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24337317/encrypt-with-php-decrypt-with-javascript-cryptojs