# CryptoJs - Encrypt/Decrypt by PHP and Javascript - Simple Output Encrypted String

Tags: javascript, php, encryption, cryptojs

I want to encrypt and decrypt some string in Php and in Javascript and looking on the web, the best and safest way seems to be CryptoJs.

This post is not a duplicate of [Encrypt with PHP, Decrypt with Javascript (cryptojs)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24337317/encrypt-with-php-decrypt-with-javascript-cryptojs) because the output string it's not simple.

This is my code but the Js decrypting code doesn't work.
What is it wrong?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.2/rollups/aes.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>--- PHP ------------------</p>
    
        <?php
            function myCrypt($value, $passphrase, $iv){
                $encrypted_data = openssl_encrypt($value, 'aes-256-cbc', $passphrase, true, $iv);
                return base64_encode($encrypted_data);
            }
            
            function myDecrypt($value, $passphrase, $iv){
                $value = base64_decode($value);
                $data = openssl_decrypt($value, 'aes-256-cbc', $passphrase, true, $iv);
                return $data;
            }
            

            $valTxt="MyText";
            $pswd="MyPassword";
            $vector="1234567890123412";
            $encrypted = myCrypt($valTxt, $pswd, $vector);
            $decrypted = myDecrypt($encrypted, $pswd, $vector);
            
            echo "<p>Text to crypt --------> ".$valTxt." </p>";
            echo "<p>Password: ".$pswd." </p>";
            echo "<p>Vector: ".$vector." </p>";
            echo "<p>TextEncrypt: ".$encrypted." </p>";
            echo "<p>TextDecrypt: ".$decrypted." </p>";
        ?>
        
        <br><br><br>
        <p>--- Javascript ------------------</p>
        <p>JS-DataEncrypt: --------- <span id="DataEncrypt"></span></p>
        <p>JS-DataPassword: -------- <span id="DataPassword"></span></p>
        <p>JS-DataVector: ---------- <span id="DataVector"></span></p>
        <p>JS-TextDecrypted: ------- <span id="result"></span></p>
        
        <script>
            var DataEncrypt='<?php echo $encrypted;?>';
            var DataPassword='<?php echo $pswd;?>';
            var DataVector='<?php echo $vector;?>';
            
            //var key = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(DataPassword);
            //var iv = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(DataVector);
            //var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(DataEncrypt, key, { iv: iv });
            
            var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(DataEncrypt, DataPassword, { iv: DataVector });
            
            decrypted= CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.stringify(decrypted)
            
            
            
            document.getElementById("DataEncrypt").innerHTML = DataEncrypt;
            document.getElementById("DataPassword").innerHTML = DataPassword;
            document.getElementById("DataVector").innerHTML = DataVector;
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = decrypted;
        </script>
    
    
        
    </body>
</html>
```

PS. Better if the output string ($encrypted) will be 16 digits A-Za-z0-9... is it possible changing 'aes-256-cbc'?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the PHP code the following should be considered:

- `$passphrase` does not denote a passphrase, but the key. This key must be 32 bytes in size for the choice `aes-256-cbc`. If it is too short, it is filled with 0 values, if it is too long, it is truncated. This is a common source of error, so a key of exactly 32 bytes should be used. If you want to work with a passphrase, you have to use a KDF (like PBKDF2).
- In the fourth parameter flags are set, and no boolean expression (like `true`). If the data should be returned in binary form, the `OPENSSL_RAW_DATA` flag must be set.
- Static IVs are insecure, usually a new IV is generated for each encryption, which is sent to the recipient together with the ciphertext. Since the IV is not secret, it is usually placed in front of the ciphertext on byte level without encryption.

The following sample PHP code (based on the posted code):

```
function myCrypt($value, $key, $iv){
    $encrypted_data = openssl_encrypt($value, 'aes-256-cbc', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
    return base64_encode($encrypted_data);
}

function myDecrypt($value, $key, $iv){
    $value = base64_decode($value);
    $data = openssl_decrypt($value, 'aes-256-cbc', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
    return $data;
}

$valTxt="MyText";
$key="01234567890123456789012345678901"; // 32 bytes
$vector="1234567890123412"; // 16 bytes
$encrypted = myCrypt($valTxt, $key, $vector);
$decrypted = myDecrypt($encrypted, $key, $vector);
print($encrypted . "\n");
print($decrypted . "\n");
```

returns the following result:

```
1SF+kez1CE5Rci3H6ff8og==
MyText
```

---

The corresponding CryptoJS code for decryption is:

```js
var DataEncrypt = "1SF+kez1CE5Rci3H6ff8og==";
var DataKey = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("01234567890123456789012345678901");
var DataVector = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("1234567890123412");
var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(DataEncrypt, DataKey, { iv: DataVector });        
var decrypted = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.stringify(decrypted);
console.log(decrypted);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.0.0/crypto-js.min.js"></script>
```

with the output `MyText` which corresponds to the original plaintext.

It is important that the key is passed as `WordArray`, so that it is interpreted as a key and not as a passphrase. For the conversion CryptoJS provides encoders (like `CryptoJS.enc.Utf8`).

---

Regarding your question at the end: Ciphertexts are binary arbitrary sequences that can be converted to a string with special binary-to-text encodings (e.g. Base64 as in this case, or hexadecimal), which is generally longer than the raw data (Base64: 75% efficiency, hexadecimal: 50% efficiency, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-to-text_encoding)).
The representation of a ciphertext block with a number of alphanumeric characters (e.g. 16 chars) equal to the block size (e.g. 16 bytes for AES) is therefore generally not possible.
Note that converting to a string with a character set encoding such as UTF8 is not a solution either, but would corrupt the data.

Comment: Thanks, so much... now I have decided to encode with aes-128-ofb
In this case the key must be 16 digits.
Encode and Decode in PHP work, but not in Javascript... but on CryptoJs aes-128-ofb is accepted.
What is it wrong? Here the JsTest https://jsfiddle.net/qtbapwn7/

function myCrypt($value, $key, $iv){
    $encrypted_data = openssl_encrypt($value, 'aes-128-ofb', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
    return base64_encode($encrypted_data);
}

$valTxt="MyText";
$key="1234567890123456";
$vector="1234567890123412";
$encrypted = myCrypt($valTxt, $key, $vector);
echo $encrypted; //GlwC/kGs

Comment: In the curly brackets, in addition to the IV, the mode and padding must be defined: `{ iv: DataVectorUtf8, mode: CryptoJS.mode.OFB, padding: CryptoJS.pad.NoPadding}`. Please post a new question if there are more questions, otherwise this question becomes confusing and code in comments is hard to read. Thank you.

Comment: ok... but there is an error... look here: https://jsfiddle.net/2agtx8sd/ 
do i have to make a new post?

Comment: You need to click on the _Resources_ link on the left panel and add a reference for CryptoJS (e.g. _https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.0.0/crypto-js.min.js_). Then click on the _plus sign_. After that your reference is added and your code will be successfully executed, s. https://jsfiddle.net/ws0qj71e/