# Can't decrypt CryptoJS-encrypted strings in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, encryption, openssl, cryptojs

First of all, I'm a newbie in this subject. This is the first time I need to send encrypted data from front-end to back-end in a secure way.

I'm trying to use CryptoJS to encrypt some sensitive data (credit card information) and send it to my PHP backend, where I need to decrypt it to use with the integration with my payment gateway.

This is my JS code:

```js
let card_number = form.find("input#card_number").val();
let card_holder = form.find("input#card_holder").val();
let card_expiration_date = form.find("input#card_expiration_date").val();
let card_cvv = form.find("input#card_cvv").val();

let key = globalSettings.encryption_key;

card_number = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(card_number, key);
card_holder = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(card_holder, key);
card_expiration_date = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(card_expiration_date, key);
card_cvv = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(card_cvv, key);

formData = {
    card_number: card_number.toString(),
    card_holder: card_holder.toString(),
    card_expiration_date: card_expiration_date.toString(),
    card_cvv: card_cvv.toString(),
};
```

For note, the `globalSettings` object is sent from backend with configured keys. The generated `formData` object is sent to back-end with no problem. But, when trying to decrypt the values with `openssl_decrypt`, I'm only getting `false` results.

Here is my PHP code:

```php
$card_number = $request->get("card_number");
$card_holder = $request->get("card_holder");
$card_expiration_date = $request->get("card_expiration_date");
$card_cvv = $request->get("card_cvv");

$key = ENCRYPTION_KEY;
$method = "AES-256-CBC";

$card_number = openssl_decrypt($card_number, $method, $key);
$card_holder = openssl_decrypt($card_holder, $method, $key);
$card_expiration_date = openssl_decrypt($card_expiration_date, $method, $key);
$card_cvv = openssl_decrypt($card_cvv, $method, $key);
```

Before applying `openssl_decrypt`, the variables are exact the same as sent from front-end. But, after applying `openssl_decrypt`, they are all changed to `false`, and I can't figure out why and how to fix it to get back decrypted information.

Comment: What is the purpose of encrypting the data manually? If you use SSL (which you _really_ need to do if you handle payment details), all traffic between the client and server will already be encrypted. That's what it's for, after all!

Comment: Yes, I know SSL will handle that. But my client is very rigorous with sensitive data, and his Information Security department asked me to send encrypted data, even using SSL. They have an MITM and DDOS attack history, so this is a way they can feel more secure about users sensitive data.

Comment: To be honest, you should really educate the client that this won't really make it more secure during transmission. And point out that even big banks and security companies rely on SSL for protecting their traffic.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Encrypt with PHP, Decrypt with Javascript (cryptojs)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24337317/encrypt-with-php-decrypt-with-javascript-cryptojs)

Comment: In the CryptoJS code, is `key` a `WordArray` or a string? I guess it's a string. In this case CryptoJS uses a key derivation (`EVP_BytesToKey()`) which is not applied in the PHP code.

Comment: @BhaumikPandhi Unfortunately, no. I need to encrypt data with JS, then decrypt in PHP.

Comment: @Topaco Yes, the key is a string. It is a complex password (32 chars mixing letters, numbers and symbols). Now, how can I apply this derivatiom EVP_BytesToKey you said in PHP ?

Comment: @RBFraphael, the link I shared works both ways, JavaScript to PHP and only JavaScript or only PHP.

Comment: You can find various `EVP_BytesToKey()` implementations on the web, e.g. [here](https://gist.github.com/ezimuel/67fa19030c75052b0dde278a383eda1b#file-decrypt-php-L43). Note that CryptoJS applies MD5 instead of SHA256 so you've to replace 'sha256' with 'md5' in [line 49](https://gist.github.com/ezimuel/67fa19030c75052b0dde278a383eda1b#file-decrypt-php-L49).