# How to use this code for encrypted and decrypted use java spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, encryption, aes

I need your help, how to use library CryptoJS in spring boot. In my client use this library from https://stackoverflow.com/a/27582253
But i'm difficult to find an solution for decrypted. For example in my client has an encrupted like this:

```
var encData  = {"ct":"d97K/kt03Inh9wYp90iyNwefnaTwMAeQXTjOwJR+gU0=","iv":"4101e6c0938e312952ea24f19306cfb2","s":"615cc2b4480e260a"}
```

for the `public_key = S!ZcdNb4XXcw_jXbHQqiFsHp6`

So how to decrypted the encData in server side use spring boot ?

i've been try to use `javax.crypto` but always getting an error
`Wrong IV length: must be 16 bytes long`

```
    public static String decrypt(String passphrase, String jsonString) throws Exception {
        JsonObject jsonObject = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, JsonObject.class);
        String saltHex = jsonObject.get("s").getAsString();
        String ctBase64 = jsonObject.get("ct").getAsString();
        String ivHex = jsonObject.get("iv").getAsString();
        System.out.println(passphrase);

        byte[] salt = hexStringToByteArray(saltHex);
        byte[] ct = Base64.getDecoder().decode(ctBase64);
        byte[] iv = hexStringToByteArray(ivHex);

        //String concatedPassphrase = passphrase + new String(salt, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        String concatedPassphrase = passphrase + byteArrayToString(salt);
        System.out.println(concatedPassphrase);
        byte[] md5 = md5(concatedPassphrase.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

        for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
            md5 = md5(concatArrays(md5, concatedPassphrase.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
        }

        byte[] key = Arrays.copyOf(md5, 32);
        SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
        IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

        try {
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, ivSpec);
            byte[] decryptedData = cipher.doFinal(ct);
            return new String(decryptedData, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //e.printStackTrace();
            return e.getMessage();
        }
    }
```

Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

You have ported the key derivation function incorrectly. Correct is e.g.:

```java
...
byte[] concatedPassphrase = concatArrays(passphrase.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), salt);
byte[] md5 = md5(concatedPassphrase);
byte[] result = md5;
for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
    md5 = md5(concatArrays(md5, concatedPassphrase));
    result = concatArrays(result, md5);
}
byte[] key = Arrays.copyOf(result, 32);
...
```

With this change decryption works.

---

Note that the key derivation function should implement the OpenSSL proprietary key derivation function `EVP_BytesToKey()` (at least the partial functionality required here). As an alternative to the user-defined implementation, the BouncyCastle implementation of `EVP_BytesToKey()` can also be used (if this is possible in your environment):

```java
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.digests.MD5Digest;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.generators.OpenSSLPBEParametersGenerator;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.KeyParameter;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.ParametersWithIV;
...
OpenSSLPBEParametersGenerator pbeGenerator = new OpenSSLPBEParametersGenerator(new MD5Digest()); 
pbeGenerator.init(passphrase.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), salt);
ParametersWithIV parameters = (ParametersWithIV) pbeGenerator.generateDerivedParameters(256, 0); // keySize, ivSize in bits
byte[] key = ((KeyParameter)parameters.getParameters()).getKey();
```

Hint: BouncyCastle also provides various encoders (e.g. for hex encoding/decoding).

---

Security: Note that `EVP_BytesToKey()` is considered insecure today. More reliable key derivation functions are Argon2 or at least PBKDF2 (in conjunction with a random salt).