# URL redirection with passing variables between two domains

Tags: php

I have a problem. I need to pass variables from one site to another site.
I don't want to use GET method as I need to pass some secure variables.

How would I do it?

Comment: In terms of security, POST and GET are equally insecure; an alternative approach is to encrypt the variables, provided that the domain you're redirecting to can decrypt it again. There are more elaborate ways, such as a token based mechanism (whereby the actual data is transferred by the server but the client only uses an opaque identifier).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best (and most simple) bet if you're concerned about security would be to:

1. Using cURL over SSL, create a new POST to server 2
2. After the POST is complete, server 2 will respond with a TOKEN
3. Use this token in your GET request / browser redirect from server 1
4. On server 2, check the token and find the data

This is a simple way of doing a secure "pass" of data... albeit, there are more elegant solutions.

See example of flow:

[image: Example of flow]

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider http POST? It works just like GET, as far as its PHP/HTML implementation: `<form action="inputUrl.php" method="post">` for sending and `$_POST["var"]` for receiving.

As far as security goes, POST is much better than GET, as the data is sent behind-the-scenes, rather than embedded in the URL, making it the typical protocol for login info. It also works well for one-time actions, like purchases. However, it still sends data in plain-text by default, so you should definitely enable encryption/decryption on the two respective servers to enforce data security. You can do this easily enough with PHP; [look into the](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16600708/how-do-you-encrypt-and-decrypt-a-php-string) `crypt()` function.

Comment: I cannot tell a browser to make a post request through an HTTP header. The location header will redirect, but only for GET or HEAD requests.

Comment: I wouldn't say POST is much better; while it's (marginally) more obfuscated, the client can still inspect the payload.

Comment: When I wrote this, I assumed your server does not have SSL. Otherwise, @Half Crazed is definitely the better solution (but it still technically uses POST!)

Comment: Correct - it does post, but the user is completely unaware of the payload. Though an attacker could be a "man in the middle" or even attack server 2 and cross reference the token to find the data. There's a ton of ways to prevent this, but I felt like my solution was one of the easier ones heh