# API encrypting url and can't decrypt with mcrypt as it returns null

Tags: php, encryption

I am trying to send over an encrypted URL and then decode it at the other end. Now the call I make is passed over but my decryption returns null.

Here's some of my code.

```
$this->_app_url . '?key=' . $this->_api_key . '&request=' .base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $this->_api_key, json_encode($url), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB));
```

The url is just a standard url, the key is a 32bit string so you can imagine it as anything. The $url variable is an array of stuff to be sent over. So that when I decrypt I have that array outright.

So at the other end I am trying to decode:

```
$key = $_REQUEST["key"];
$encrypted = $_REQUEST["request"];

$decrypted = json_decode(rtrim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, base64_decode($encrypted), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB)));
```

This simply returns `NULL`, I can echo out the key and request and I get what i'm expecting but I just can't decrypt it.

Comment: Did you check `json_last_error`?

Comment: can you try `utf8_encode` before `json_decode` ?

Comment: still gives the same error if i put it before the decode.

Comment: Please don't use `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256` in ECB mode. Also, why are you transmitting the key?

Comment: What do you suggest i use? - transmitting the key  for test purpose, later it will test keys from database.

Comment: Oh, I have an = in my base64_encode() so i added urlencode before and then urldecode() before the decryption of the base64 to fix it.

Comment: In order of decreasing preference: [libsodium](https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium-php) (`crypto_secretbox()`) if you can, or one of these: [`defuse/php-encryption`](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption) or [`\Zend\Crypt`](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-crypt).

Comment: @ScottArciszewski You forgot the most important one: SSL. Why encrypt just part of the data when you can encrypt the whole interaction?

Comment: Right, I was hoping `$this->_app_url` included `https://` at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

This question has been asked a lot, with different word choice (which makes it difficult to say, "Just search for it!"). This fact prompted a blog post titled, [The Comprehensive Guide to URL Parameter Encryption in PHP](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/09/comprehensive-guide-url-parameter-encryption-in-php) .

#### What People Want To Do Here

[image: Some encryption function is used to deterministically retrieve the ID]

#### What People Should Do Instead

[image: Use a separate column]

#### Explanation

Typically, people want *short* random-looking URLs. This doesn't allow you much room to [encrypt then authenticate](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/05/using-encryption-and-authentication-correctly) the database record ID you wish to obfuscate. Doing so would require a minimum URL length of 32 bytes (for HMAC-SHA256), which is 44 characters when encoded in base64.

A simpler strategy is to generate a random string (see [random_compat](https://github.com/paragonie/random_compat) for a PHP5 implementation of `random_bytes()` and `random_int()` for generating these strings) and reference that column instead.

If you *must* encrypt data (very much NOT recommended), don't use a homegrown design (and [don't use mcrypt either](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/05/if-you-re-typing-word-mcrypt-into-your-code-you-re-doing-it-wrong)!). Use a [trustworthy library instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30159120/2224584).