# Japanese/korean into MySQL table

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, converters

i am trying to store some info in my db. One of the fields are Japanese names. I am getting a error:

```
Warning: #1366 Incorrect string value: '\xE3\x83\xA9\xE3\x83\x87...' for column 'japan-name' at row 1
```

So i cannot chnage the charset of my db. Can i use PHP or Javascript to convert Japanese/Korean to something else, and them when i go read it, reconvert to Japanese/Korean?

Comment: try 1) backup the table   2) truncate old table  3) apply modification and then 4) restore data

Comment: i really need to use something to convert.

Comment: utf-8 saves the unicode data in table... but other way is to encode and save and then decode and display

Comment: Thats what i was asking..

Comment: i will still say that encoding and decoding is not a good approach as you will not be able to search in database

Comment: This is lacking critical information. What charset are you using for the table/column, what charset is the text you're trying to insert in? Why can't you convert the charset? If you're going to work with "international" text, your database should support it.

Comment: @AsadNauman and William Philippe:  One word, seven letters.  R E S P E C T.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP offers the [`base64_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) and [`base64_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php) functions. They are fast, and impose a storage penalty of about 33%. You can use the first to convert your utf-8 east Asian text to what looks like gibberish in ASCII before you store it in your table.  The second will convert it back after you retrieve it.

Here's an example:

```
$jp = " 私はガラスを食べられます。それは私を傷つけません。";
$jpe = base64_encode ($jp);
$jpd = base64_decode ($jpe);
```

After you run these lines, the `$jpe` variable has the value

> IOengeOBr+OCrOODqeOCueOCkumjn+OBueOCieOCjOOBvuOBmeOAguOBneOCjOOBr+engeOCkuWCt+OBpOOBkeOBvuOBm+OCk+OAgg==

That stores just fine in an ASCII or Latin-1 column.

Answer (score -2):

utf-8 saves the unicode data in table... but other way is to encode and save and then decode and display

**update**:
searched on web and found answer at [How do you Encrypt and Decrypt a PHP String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16600708/how-do-you-encrypt-and-decrypt-a-php-string)

```
define("ENCRYPTION_KEY", "!@#$%^&*");
$string = "This is the original data string!";

echo $encrypted = encrypt($string, ENCRYPTION_KEY);
echo "<br />";
echo $decrypted = decrypt($encrypted, ENCRYPTION_KEY);

/**
 * Returns an encrypted & utf8-encoded
 */
function encrypt($pure_string, $encryption_key) {
    $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
    $encrypted_string = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, $encryption_key, utf8_encode($pure_string), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
    return $encrypted_string;
}

/**
 * Returns decrypted original string
 */
function decrypt($encrypted_string, $encryption_key) {
    $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
    $decrypted_string = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, $encryption_key, $encrypted_string, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
    return $decrypted_string;
}
```

Comment: LOl is not correct you just writted what i asked. I need something to convert... some command...i dont need you to repeat what i asked LOOOL

Comment: So if you are not going to help me with some php command convert or javascript function i will not mark as correct.

Comment: Seriously? **Encryption** to solve a problem with charsets? Just no.

Comment: instead of giving negative point straight forward you should read my comments where user does not wanted to change the database type. and I have also commented on the same time that it is not recommended :(

Comment: Regardless of that, there are any number of simple **encodings** which could solve this problem, instead of a completely misplaced **encryption** algorithm.