# Encrypt / Decrypt Text using PHP - 16 characters or shorter

Tags: php, encryption

I'd like to store user id's in google analytics however since they have a policy of not allowing this, I want to encrypt some text in php and be able to decrypt when needed(The User Id).

The catch is I'd like it to be as short as possible.  How can I achieve this.  I'm not worried at all for this to be secure.  Just need to mask it some fashion.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you Encrypt and Decrypt a PHP String?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16600708/how-do-you-encrypt-and-decrypt-a-php-string)

Answer (score 0):

The [simple and most seure solution to encrypting URL parameters](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/09/comprehensive-guide-url-parameter-encryption-in-php) is to not encrypt them at all. Instead use a randomly generated unique value, store it in another column in the desired database table, and select based on that.

For example:

```
function generateToken()
{
    return strtr('+/', '-_', base64_encode(random_bytes(9)));
}
```

And when retrieving:

```
$data = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE selector = ?")->execute([
    $_GET['user_token']
]);
```