# PHP Openssl Encrypt Data For URL

Tags: php, encryption

I have this code :

```
<?php

$key = 'thisisakey';
$iv = '1234567812345678';

$plaintext = 'Hello World';

$ciphertext = openssl_encrypt($plaintext,  'AES-128-CBC', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
echo $ciphertext . '<br>';

$plaintext  = openssl_decrypt($ciphertext, 'AES-128-CBC', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv); 
echo $plaintext . '<br>';

?>
```

The idea behind this code was encrypt the data to be used on the URL. So, I'm expecting output which URL friendly. I mean, it contains alpha-numeric characters only. But when I use this `openssl_encrypt` function, I got weird characters, which I don't think URL friendly.

it produces output like this :

```
^‘-7È¾®l¿ô¾áÙ
```

how to generate URL friendly characters from `openssl_encrypt`? thank you

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Answer (score 7):

This question has been asked a lot, with different word choice (which makes it difficult to say, "Just search for it!"). This fact prompted a blog post titled, [The Comprehensive Guide to URL Parameter Encryption in PHP](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/09/comprehensive-guide-url-parameter-encryption-in-php) .

#### What People Want To Do Here

[image: Some encryption function is used to deterministically retrieve the ID]

#### What People Should Do Instead

[image: Use a separate column]

#### Explanation

Typically, people want *short* random-looking URLs. This doesn't allow you much room to [encrypt then authenticate](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/05/using-encryption-and-authentication-correctly) the database record ID you wish to obfuscate. Doing so would require a minimum URL length of 32 bytes (for HMAC-SHA256), which is 44 characters when encoded in base64.

A simpler strategy is to generate a random string (see [random_compat](https://github.com/paragonie/random_compat) for a PHP5 implementation of `random_bytes()` and `random_int()` for generating these strings) and reference that column instead.

#### What To Do If Encryption Is Non-Negotiable?

If you *must* encrypt data (very much NOT recommended), don't use a homegrown design (especially [unauthenticated CBC mode](https://robertheaton.com/2013/07/29/padding-oracle-attack)). Use a [trustworthy library instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30159120/2224584).

Once you have encryption working, make sure you the ciphertext uses [hex or base64url encoding](https://github.com/paragonie/constant_time_encoding).