# What is the safest method in php to generate NOT random password in php?

Tags: php

I did some research and all the method to generate passwords seems to include a 'random' part. What if I want to generate a password, secure as possible, with no random parts, so to be able to have a script generating it (again and again with the same result)?

Let's say in my website I have a user having username 'foo_bar'. Doing something like

```
   hash('sha512', 'foo_bar'.'some_secret_word')
```

to generate his password could be the best way to proceed?

EDIT: I need my script to generate the same password giving it in input the same string, so everything involving rand() is not an answer

EDIT: Let's detail the problem. I have a long list of user data (username,email,address,etc) in a csv form. I have to import them inside my website (built on a CMS). I know how to import them, generating users, but I need to generate, by my own php, their password, in order to see them at any time, for I need to print the credentials to the users at different times. Generating passwords with any random element means not to be able to have and print the credential at any time. For some reasons, I can't simply generate them one time, store them somewhere and check later. Obviously, I can't generate password with a simple method like password='username_astring' for any user looking at his own password would know everyone else's password, so I was thinking a good way was using this method, but encrypting the string. However this idea seems not quite 'clean' to me and I was guessing if there is a more standard and clean solution.

Comment: The random bit (salt) is part of what makes hashes secure. Please just use the [Password API](http://php.net/password) and stop trying to roll your own password workflow.

Comment: What do you mean by "safe"?

Comment: Are you trying to generate the password or generate a hash? It's not clear.

Comment: @Scott By safe, I mean difficult to guess. I am not very into cryptography, and I would like to generate passwords that are not guessable like 'foo_bar_password'. At the same time, I don't need password strong enough to secure the Batcave. :)

Comment: @Machavity Password. I'm sorry, but I don't really know what a hash or a salt is.

Comment: Are you asking about automatically generating a for the user to use when he/she is logging in to your site, or are you asking about hashing an existing password to store in your database?

Comment: Truly, I have a long list of user data (username,email,address,etc) in a csv form. I have to import them inside my website (built on a CMS). I know how to import them, generating users, but I need to generate by my own their password in order to see them at any time, for I need to print the credentials to the users at different times. Generating passwords with any random element means not to be able to have and print the credential at any time. For some reasons, I can't simply generate them one time, store them somewhere and check later.

Comment: I have an answer to this question - but can't submit because its closed.

Comment: @SashaGrievus if you need to know the credentials, you don't need a hashing algorithm you need two-way encryption.

Comment: The issue with **not using `'some_secret_word'`** in the code means that if two or more people use the same password then it generates the same 'sha256' value. People tend to use 'easy to remember passwords' i.e. simple. So, crack one unsalted hash and everyone that use that password can be decrypted without any extra work.

Comment: While I think the question is flawed and might not be what the user is looking for - the question is still valid and not a duplicate of "how to create a password". Its more likely a duplicate of "How do I encrypt a string?" in this case, the string would be username.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I think I explained all the issue in a bad bad way. It's more like that I need to 'encrypt a string with salt'. The fact I would use that as a password is not quite relevant. I'm getting the point only now, understanding  the concept of hash. I'll check the two-way encryption thing.

Comment: @Scott Yes, it's closed, but it wasn't me. Someone misunderstood the question, marking it as duplicate...

Comment: @SashaGrievus Even clarified, though, it's still a duplicate, just of a different question. If you're wanting reversible encryption then you need to read [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16600708/how-do-you-encrypt-and-decrypt-a-php-string), which has probably the best answer you'll get on the topic anywhere

Comment: @Machavity I still think it is not a duplicate. It's still more complicated than simple encryption. Encrypting doesn't solve totally the problem for an encrypted string, as you say, is reversible and, if reverted, could unveil the pattern behind the generation of all the other users password. I believe the problem is not trivial and could have not trivial answers still.

Comment: why not? Doing it would cause problems? (Supposing the value hashed will be re-hashed at the moment to store it in the database as user password) It is not the standard way to deal with the problem, but could be suitable to solve my problem, anyway?

Answer (score 1):

What you are referring to is the practice of [salting](https://www.sitepoint.com/hashing-passwords-php-5-5-password-hashing-api/) passwords.  You are correct in the idea, prior to the hashing algorithm being applied to the user's password a separate string is added on to it.  What it is meant to protect against are so-called [rainbow tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table#Defense_against_rainbow_tables) where attackers will precompute hashes of common passwords and compare those to hashed passwords from database dumps they have 'obtained'.

The best practice in this case is to [not roll your own hashing algorithm](http://blog.zend.com/2016/04/07/hubris-is-not-a-security-trait/).  There's plenty of 3rd-party hashing libraries out there that are tried and tested and proven to be secure.

Barring that, best practice would be to generate a different salt for *each different password* (including password changes), which must then also be stored along with the password in order to check against authentication attempts.

Comment: The OP has clarified his question. He wants reversible passwords with salt. Good answer on hashes, tho

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion about changing the salt every time: really precious!