# What the URL Encryption ways in laravel?

Tags: php, html, laravel, encryption

I am passing the POST Id values through the URL like this

```
localhost:81/laravel/public/Application/1956458
```

So I would like to encrypt the Keys in the address bar. How can i achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some different ways to Encrypt your password,

**1. Normal Encryption.**

This is a strong AES encryption via the Mcrypt PHP extension,

```
$encrypted = Crypt::encrypt($id);
```

And also you can decrypt this encrypted values using this command,

```
$decrypted = Crypt::decrypt($encrypted);
```

**2. Hashing A Password Using Bcrypt in Laravel.**

This will create a hashed password. You may use it in your controller or even in a model.

```
$encrypted = Hash::make($id);
```

**3. Direct Use Bcrypt.**

In Laravel 5 you can directly encrypt the password using Bcrypt,

```
$encrypted = bcrypt($id);
```

Comment: So anyone can decrypt my Id using this first commands? How is this secure?

Comment: @user7354735 to be able to decode the id you need no.1 or just use plain php functions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16600708/how-do-you-encrypt-and-decrypt-a-php-string http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289061/best-way-to-use-php-to-encrypt-and-decrypt-passwords

Answer (score 2):

Use this code to encrypt and decrypt

```
$encrypt_val = Crypt::encrypt($value);
$decrypt_val = Crypt::decrypt($encrypt_val );
```

when you use `decrypt` please insert`use Illuminate\Contracts\Encryption\DecryptException;`