# Encrypting a string in web (PHP)

Tags: php, html, encryption

I'm fairly new to PHP and very new to encrypting using PHP, I've read up on some forums and watched some videos about it however as much as I try, it never encrypts properly. This is my code below to test (I know I shouldn't be md5 it's just to see if it works at first).

When I run this code on my website it tells me page is not responding meaning there is an error, however I cannot spot one or see where I went wrong.

```
<?php

$key = md5('pass');

function encrypt($string, $key){
    $string = rtrim(base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $string, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB)));
    return $string;
}

$output = encrypt("test", $key);
echo $output;

?>
```

Comment: Check your error logs and see what the actual error message is, or turn on `dsiplay_errors` in your local php.ini file, while developing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you Encrypt and Decrypt a PHP String?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16600708/how-do-you-encrypt-and-decrypt-a-php-string)

Comment: Im not familiar with php.ini and am uploading to FTP as I am working?

Comment: Depends on your installation. Create a php page with this content: `<?php phpinfo() ?>`. Browse to the page and you should see a lot of info, including where the error log is. However, you should really not roll your own encryption functions. Check for a solid up to date library for that instead, like defuse/php-encryption, or similar

Comment: |  error_log  | no value  | no value, it displays no value for all error_log options

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't be using MD5 to encrypt anything, passwords especially.

Look into php's `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` functions. Not only are they more secure than what you're doing right now, they're simpler to use as well.

Comment: The only nit I have to pick with this answer is that MD5 is not encryption.

Comment: That's correct, it's not encryption. But OP is asking about encryption, by their title. 

If they had said they were interested in creating quick to verify checksums, then MD5 may be more appropriate, except not because it's [horribly flawed](https://natmchugh.blogspot.co.at/2014/10/how-i-created-two-images-with-same-md5.html) at this point. (with plenty of other examples out there).