# How to get php hash_pbkdf2 decrypted value

Tags: php, security, cryptography, password-hash, pbkdf2

I have encrypted the string using PHP hash_pbkdf2 function. Please review the below code:

```
$password = "password";
$iterations = 10000;
$salt = 1111;

$hash = hash_pbkdf2("sha256", $password, $salt, $iterations, 20);
```

The result of hash value "61ea90120ac05230465c"

Everything working fine in encryption.

Please let me know how to decrypt the value "61ea90120ac05230465c" and get the result of "password".

Comment: [hashing != encrypting](https://www.securityinnovationeurope.com/blog/page/whats-the-difference-between-hashing-and-encrypting)

Comment: hash function can't decrypt. this is one way function. if you need encrypt and decrypt then used A3 (encryption cipher ) but this is bad way for password

Comment: if you think one could easily 'decrypt' this hash - why would you then wanna use it?

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: You can't. Might I recommend [this approach instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30159120/2224584)?

---

Longer answer (excerpted from [this article](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/08/you-wouldnt-base64-a-password-cryptography-decoded#passwords) which explains cryptography terms to developers):

> Many developers think passwords should be *encrypted*, but this is false. **Passwords should be *hashed***, not encrypted. Furthermore, don't confuse password hashing algorithms with simple cryptographic hash functions. They're not the same thing:
>
> [image: Table comparing cryptographic hashes versus password hashes]
>
> Unlike cryptographic hashes, password hashes require more than one input parameter. But unlike encryption algorithms, password hashes are one-way deterministic trap door calculations. Also unlike secret-key encryption, the salt does not need to remain secret; it merely needs to be unique per user. The purpose of a unique salt per user is to thwart pre-computation and to make brute-force guessing passwords from a list of hashes more expensive.

The function `hash_pbkdf2()` is a type of hash function, so [you cannot decrypt it](https://www.securityinnovationeurope.com/blog/page/whats-the-difference-between-hashing-and-encrypting).

Furthermore, the name of the algorithm it uses is PBKDF2, or **P**assword-**B**ased **K**ey **D**erivation **F**unction #**2**. It was designed to turn a password (a low-entropy human-sourced and human-memorizable input) into a secure cryptography key. The way it does this under the hood led a lot of people to use PBKDF2 as a password hash.

While there are some key differences between KDFs and password hashing algorithms, for the sake of *this* answer, they're **essentially the same type of algorithm**.

So the answer to "how to [decrypt] this PBKDF2 output?" is: **You can't.**

Hash functions are one-way. There are infinite inputs that can produce any given hash output, but because the output keyspace is so vast with secure hash functions, it's computationally infeasible to generate a collision.

This is also true of password hashing functions (and key derivation functions), except exacerbated by:

1. Salting
2. Iterated hashing
3. (In some cases) Memory-hard algorithm designs that make it difficult to perform a [brute force attack](https://pthree.org/2016/06/19/the-physics-of-brute-force) by using parallel processing.

The solution is to **use the right tool for the job**. And if you don't know what that is, [start here](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/08/you-wouldnt-base64-a-password-cryptography-decoded) so you understand the terms, then [see this answer for example code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30159120/2224584).